# Class path missing for custom generated jar from M2 repo in maven

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, classpath, m2eclipse

I have a multi module project .

Uaaper is parent pom

UaaPersi is child pom.

UaaClient is third application that uses jar generated by UaaPersi

I have successfully installed UaaPersi jar in my local repo using mvn install command .

Now i have UaaClient that uses UaaPersi jar . The dependency for UaaClient is below shown

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>UaaClient</groupId>
  <artifactId>ThirdPartyApp</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>war</packaging>

  <name>ThirdPartyApp</name>
   <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
  </properties>

  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
 <!-- this jar is generated by me  -->
     <dependency>
      <groupId>Uaaper</groupId>
      <artifactId>Uaapersi</artifactId>
      <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    </dependency>

  </dependencies>
</project>
```

When i do eclipse:eclipse

All dependency related to jar Uaapersi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT is included in class path for project UaaClient  .But,the jar Uaapersi-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT in classpath it is missing .

When i look at class path it is as below

```
<classpath>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/test/java" output="target/test-classes" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="src/main/java" including="**/*.java"/>
  <classpathentry kind="output" path="target/classes"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/validation/validation-api/1.1.0.Final/validation-api-1.1.0.Final.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/inject/javax.inject/1/javax.inject-1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/mail/mail/1.4.3/mail-1.4.3.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/javax/activation/activation/1.1/activation-1.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="con" path="org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONTAINER"/>
  <classpathentry kind="var" path="M2_REPO/junit/junit/3.8.1/junit-3.8.1.jar"/>
  <classpathentry kind="src" path="/Uaapersi"/>
```

**Class path from M2_REPO for Uaapersi is missing**

```
 <classpathentry kind="src" path="/Uaapersi"/>
```

It seems like i need to do extra configuration when i put jar generated by me on local repo as the result of which class path is not set from M2 repo .  But,when i do mvn package and in the war file this jar is present .

**What extra configuration do i have to make so that the class path for jar is set from local repo?**

**Help me please**

Answer (score 1):

by default eclipse maven plugin takes project from workspace and puts it into classpath, to disable this behavior and force it to look into maven local repository you need to

```
right click on your UaaClient > maven > disable workspace resolution
```

[image]

and then refresh project and invoke

```
clean compile eclipse:eclipse
```

with maven goal through eclipse maven plugin